# Using Azure table storage for ASP.NET session

Tags: asp.net, session, azure, azure-table-storage

In Azure, sessions are not sticky so it's not sufficient to use `InProc` session when you have multiple Web role instances (which you should, otherwise you're not covered by the Windows Azure Compute SLA which guarantees 99.95% uptime.).

Therefore I would like to use Azure table storage for ASP.NET session. I am familiar with SQL Azure, but have not yet used Azure table storage.

I am told that the appropriate way to do this is using the [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers), along with a small amount of `web.config` trickery.

So far, I have not been able to get this working. There are a [variety](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/Session-State-in-Windows-Azure.aspx) of postings around this topic, but a lot of them point to using `Microsoft.Samples.ServiceHosting.AspProviders.TableStorageSessionStateProvider`, which looks like a precursor to the Universal Providers being released.

At the moment, my `web.config` `sessionState` section looks like this:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom"
              customProvider="TableStorageSessionStateProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="TableStorageSessionStateProvider"
         type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

However, using this gives me an error as the provider needs to have a `connectionStringName` attribute.

For Azure table storage, what should this look like?

Comment: I think @smarx is right. Is there any reason you aren't using a SQL DB or AppFabric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the universal providers have any support for table storage.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use AppFabric Caching:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278339.aspx